# Keep QToolbar showing always all items

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtoolbar

lets consider the following screenshot:

[image]

You can see that the top toolbar displays 2 rows; however to do so , in need to click on the `>>` at the top right (circled in red) and keep hovering hover the toolbar area, which can get a bit annoying.

Is there a way to keep the 2 rows of the toolbar always displaying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

- Expand the QToolBar using the layout that in the implementation of the private API has a slot called setExpanded() that allows to expand the QToolBar.
- Hide the button, and for this case it only worked to set the size to QSize(0, 0).
- Deactivate the event Leave of the QToolBar so that it does not collapse.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ToolBar(QtWidgets.QToolBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        lay = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLayout)
        if lay is not None:
            lay.setExpanded(True)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.on_timeout)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_timeout(self):
        button = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QToolButton, "qt_toolbar_ext_button")
        if button is not None:
            button.setFixedSize(0, 0)

    def event(self, e):
        if e.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
            return True
        return super().event(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    toolbar = ToolBar()
    for i in range(20):
        toolbar.addAction("action{}".format(i))
    w.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, toolbar)

    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thx a lot your sample code works! However I wanted to use a smaller snippet of it by simply using 
        `toolbar = self.addToolBar('toolbar')
        lay = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLayout)
        lay.setExpanded(True)`
in my code (where the toolbar is), but i receive an error `'QLayout' object has no attribute 'setExpanded'`, do you know why?

Comment: @jimbasquiat in your case use:  `lay = toolbar.findChild(QtWidgets.QLayout) `